# How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I use Tilda (drop-down terminal) on Ubuntu as my "command central" - pretty much the way others might use GNOME Do, Quicksilver or Launchy.

However, I'm struggling with how to completely detach a process (e.g. Firefox) from the terminal it's been launched from - i.e. prevent that such a (non-)child process

- is terminated when closing the originating terminal
- "pollutes" the originating terminal via STDOUT/STDERR

For example, in order to start Vim in a "proper" terminal window, I have tried a simple script like the following:

```
exec gnome-terminal -e "vim $@" &> /dev/null &
```

However, that still causes pollution (also, passing a file name doesn't seem to work).

Comment: That, too, is a good question.
I think it's fair to consider Bash a programming language - although indeed the scope of this question is probably more on the sysadmin side...

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client

Comment: dup of:http://superuser.com/questions/177218/how-to-start-gui-linux-programs-from-the-command-line-but-separate-from-the-comm

Comment: Your use case does not describe complete detachment, per se.

Answer (score 445):

First of all; once you've started a process, you can background it by first stopping it (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) and then typing `bg` to let it resume in the background.  It's now a "job", and its `stdout`/`stderr`/`stdin` are still connected to your terminal.

You can start a process as backgrounded immediately by appending a "&" to the end of it:

```
firefox &
```

To run it in the background silenced, use this:

```
firefox </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

---

Some additional info:

`nohup` is a program you can use **to run your application with** such that its stdout/stderr can be sent to a file instead and such that closing the parent script won't SIGHUP the child.  However, you need to have had the foresight to have used it before you started the application.  Because of the way `nohup` works, you can't just *apply it to a running process*.

`disown` is a bash builtin that removes a shell job from the shell's job list.  What this basically means is that you can't use `fg`, `bg` on it anymore, but more importantly, when you close your shell it won't hang or send a `SIGHUP` to that child anymore.  Unlike `nohup`, `disown` is used **after** the process has been launched and backgrounded.

What you *can't* do, is change the stdout/stderr/stdin of a process after having launched it.  At least not from the shell.  If you launch your process and tell it that its stdout is your terminal (which is what you do by default), then that process is configured to output to your terminal.  Your shell has no business with the processes' FD setup, that's purely something the process itself manages.  The process itself can decide whether to close its stdout/stderr/stdin or not, but you can't use your shell to force it to do so.

To manage a background process' output, you have plenty of options from scripts, "nohup" probably being the first to come to mind.  But for interactive processes you start but forgot to silence (`firefox < /dev/null &>/dev/null &`) you can't do much, really.

I recommend you get GNU `screen`.  With screen you can just close your running shell when the process' output becomes a bother and open a new one (`^Ac`).

---

Oh, and by the way, don't use "`$@`" where you're using it.

`$@` means, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` ..., which would turn your command into:

```
gnome-terminal -e "vim $1" "$2" "$3" ...
```

That's probably not what you want because -e only takes **one** argument.  Use `$1` to show that your script can only handle one argument.

It's really difficult to get multiple arguments working properly in the scenario that you gave (with the `gnome-terminal -e`) because `-e` takes only one argument, which is a shell command string.  You'd have to encode your arguments into one.  The best and most robust, but rather cludgy, way is like so:

```
gnome-terminal -e "vim $(printf "%q " "$@")"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Sadly I can only accept one answer.
I ended up with "nohup $@ &> /dev/null &" and "alias wvim='launch.sh gnome-terminal -x vim'"

Comment: Strange: when I am did «Ctrl-z» in terminal, and next «bg», the process should not anymore relying on terminal. But when I closed the terminal, it was closed too o.O

Comment: @Hi-Angel when you close an interactive bash shell, bash HUPs all active jobs.  When you ^Z and bg a process it is still a job, be it a background one.  To remove it as a job, use `disown`, then the process will keep on living after you close the shell since bash won't HUP it anymore.

Comment: Won't using `$*` instead of `$@` fix the problem of the separate strings already?

Comment: @sjas No! That would make you inject literal data into shell code!  It will result in bugs of all sorts depending on what the arguments were and could have destructive effects (never mind that creating arbitrary code execution is very unsafe)

Comment: _What you can't do, is change the stdout/stderr/stdin of a process after having launched it._ - not exactly true. Use `reptyr` for this.

Comment: According to bash man page, `&>>/dev/null` is sufficient to redirect stderr and stdout. i.e: `firefox &>>/dev/null`

Comment: `man disown`, `help disown', and `disown --help` did not work. I found [documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html).

Answer (score 241):

```
nohup cmd &
```

[`nohup`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/nohup.html) detaches the process completely (daemonizes it)

Comment: Although succinct is valuable, completeness is more valuable. Although nohup is a GNU coreutil, a bash-only answer (or note about there not being one) would be appropriate here. Good answer nonetheless.

Comment: `nohup` just ignores the `SIGHUP` signal. It executes the process normally. No daemonization.

Comment: @nemo Which means the process is not detached, but would become detached (and a child of `init`) if the shell exited... right?

Comment: @Noldorin Yes. Ignoring SIGHUP, which is sent when the shell terminates, will leave the child process running and being relocated to init.

Comment: @nemo nohup also silences standard in/outs. Follow up with disown to completely detach.

Comment: `disown` might help too

Comment: In Linux nohup is not enough to disassociate the process from the terminal. Programs list ssh will still know what terminal are you from and ask you -for instance- if you want to add something to the known hosts lists. Other Unixes used to have setpgrp and other tricks to completely remove a process from the termios session.

Comment: Just to clarify: So `nohup cmd &> /dev/null &disown` would be the way to go (In case you don't want output in the `nohup.out` file)?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Comments are not very good at this... `user@host$ nohup mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 9892
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
user@host$ disown
user@host$`

Answer (score 80):

If you are using `bash`, try `disown [jobspec]`;
see [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Another approach you can try is `at now`.
If you're not superuser, your permission to use `at` may be restricted.

Comment: "disown" don't seem to be an internal bash command (not available on my machine, and I use bash).  "nohup", as Ben suggested, might be a much better (and standard) way of doing this.

Comment: `at` to delegate execution to someone else, I like it! +1

Comment: As a point of reference, this works in `zsh` as well.

Comment: `at now` Fantastic!

Comment: Also, `disown` doesn't seem to have the desired effect with `gnome-terminal`--`disown`ed processes are still killed when the terminal exits. I'd love to know why/how.

Comment: `disown` is perfect! Nowadays, it’s available in every bash, and does properly what is needed. As opposed to  `nohup` et al, which do some more things.

Comment: `at now` trick is clever

Comment: @KyleStrand for me `disown` detaches it completely, I can terminate the terminal and the process continue. Also note that you don't need to specify a `jobspec` if you only want to disown the last job. (using zsh)

Comment: @Xerus Interesting. I believe I was running Debian 7 or 8 when I wrote that comment; I don't remember what Bash version I had. I wonder if there was a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 57):

Reading these answers, I was under the initial impression that issuing `nohup <command> &` would be sufficient. Running zsh in gnome-terminal, I found that `nohup <command> &` did not prevent my shell from killing child processes on exit. Although `nohup` is useful, especially with non-interactive shells, it only guarantees this behavior if the child process does not reset its handler for the `SIGHUP` signal.

In my case, `nohup` should have prevented hangup signals from reaching the application, but the child application (VMWare Player in this case) was resetting its `SIGHUP` handler. As a result when the terminal emulator exits, it could still kill your subprocesses. This can only be resolved, to my knowledge, by ensuring that the process is removed from the shell's jobs table. If `nohup` is overridden with a shell builtin, as is sometimes the case, this may be sufficient, however, in the event that it is not...

---

`disown` is a shell builtin in `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh93`,

```
<command> &
disown
```

or

```
<command> &; disown
```

if you prefer one-liners. This has the generally desirable effect of removing the subprocess from the jobs table. This allows you to exit the terminal emulator without accidentally signaling the child process at all. No matter what the `SIGHUP` handler looks like, this should not kill your child process.

After the disown, the process is still a child of your terminal emulator (play with `pstree` if you want to watch this in action), but after the terminal emulator exits, you should see it attached to the init process. In other words, everything is as it should be, and as you presumably want it to be.

What to do if your shell does not support `disown`? I'd strongly advocate switching to one that does, but in the absence of that option, you have a few choices.

1. `screen` and `tmux` can solve this problem, but they are much heavier weight solutions, and I dislike having to run them for such a simple task. They are much more suitable for situations in which you want to maintain a tty, typically on a remote machine.
2. For many users, it may be desirable to see if your shell supports a capability like zsh's `setopt nohup`. This can be used to specify that `SIGHUP` should not be sent to the jobs in the jobs table when the shell exits. You can either apply this just before exiting the shell, or add it to shell configuration like `~/.zshrc` if you always want it on.
3. Find a way to edit the jobs table. I couldn't find a way to do this in `tcsh` or `csh`, which is somewhat disturbing.
4. Write a small C program to fork off and `exec()`. This is a very poor solution, but the source should only consist of a couple dozen lines. You can then pass commands as commandline arguments to the C program, and thus avoid a process specific entry in the jobs table.

Answer (score 43):

1. `nohup $COMMAND &`
2. `$COMMAND & disown`
3. `setsid command`

I've been using number 2 for a very long time, but number 3 works just as well.  Also, `disown` has a `nohup` flag of `-h`, can disown all processes with `-a`, and can disown all running processes with `-ar`.

Silencing is accomplished by `$COMMAND &>/dev/null`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Short and sweet; thanks for this very helpful summary!

Comment: I can't believe I still get notifications for this post...

Answer (score 24):

Most simple and only correct answer for bash:

```
command & disown
```

<sub><sub>You dont have to detach the process from terminal, but from the shell.</sub></sub>

Comment: This is the only sequence of commands that worked for me

Answer (score 9):

in tcsh (and maybe in other shells as well), you can use parentheses to detach the process.

Compare this:

```
> jobs # shows nothing
> firefox &
> jobs
[1]  + Running                       firefox
```

To this:

```
> jobs # shows nothing
> (firefox &)
> jobs # still shows nothing
>
```

This removes firefox from the jobs listing, but it is still tied to the terminal; if you logged in to this node via 'ssh', trying to log out will still hang the ssh process.

Answer (score 9):

I think screen might solve your problem

Answer (score 7):

To disassociate tty shell run command through sub-shell for e.g.

(command)&

When exit used terminal closed but process is still alive.

check -

```
(sleep 100) & exit
```

Open other terminal

```
ps aux | grep sleep
```

Process is still alive.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I was attempting to add a console shortcut for sublime text and it works perfectly, here's what I ended up with: ("/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" $@)&

Answer (score 6):

Backgrounding and foregrounding a job is probably one of the very first things every Unix sys-admin should know.

Here is how it is done with bash:

```
./script.sh
# suspend process
{ctrl-Z}
# background process
bg
# list all backgrounded jobs
jobs
# bring it back to foreground
fg
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run your command using the nohup command, this detach your process and redirects outputs to a given file... but I am not sure that is exactly what you need ..

Comment: I could swear I had tried nohup before using exec - but apparently not properly, as it does work like this:

nohup gnome-terminal -e "vim $@" &> /dev/null &

Answer (score 4):

To detach your program completely from your current SSH session, run:

```
setsid nohup script.sh &
```

.. and to redirect all logs (stderr & stdout), you can run:

```
setsid nohup script.sh &>/tmp/script.log &
```

---

To double check if your process got detache, run:

```
ps -efj --forest
```

and look at the hierarchical process tree.

Comment: I quite confuse when seeing that you put setsid and nohup together. We can run setsid with -f option so it will be always running in a new process. If you don't want nohup still print out to the terminal, use your second way (can remove the part setsid away too). Anything that I don't know?

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me.  My use-case:
I have a bash script: "start.sh"

The script cleans up some stuff, runs some http server, and then tails the logs generated by the server.  I run the ./start.sh script from SSH.

I wanted to be able to SSH, ./start.sh, watch the log, but also be able to press Ctrl+C to exit the "tail -f..." command - but still have the HTTP server running.

Answer (score 3):

Try [daemon](http://libslack.org/daemon/) -- should be available from your friendly package manager and comprehensively take care of every way of disassociating itself from the terminal.

Comment: This is great! You can even use it to do a bad thing, something that these other commands won't let you do (because they don't give you the chance to type your password): 

sudo daemon xed

Answer (score 3):

Just add this in your bashrc/zshrc:

```
detach() {
  "$@" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &; disown
}
```

Then you can run disowned commands like this:

```
detach gedit ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: On bash you can just do `&> /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

I have found on Mac OS X that I need to use both nohup AND disown to ensure that the child process is not torn down with the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In my .bashrc, I have these functions for precisely that purpose:

```
function run_disowned() {
    "$@" & disown
}

function dos() {
    # run_disowned and silenced

    run_disowned "$@" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}
```

Prefix a command with `dos` to run it detached from the terminal.

The function is written to work with `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: I am slightly confused as to why this answer uses  one function  wrapped into another, when its sufficient to just use one function with body like this:  `( "$@"  & disown) &> /dev/null` . It also makes not much sense to use `1>` and `2>` , because you're using `disown`, which means you are using bash, and in bash you can just easily do `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr

Comment: I have it as two functions because (1) I think it's easier to read this way, and (2) I need the `run_disowned` functionality in other places in my dotfiles. You're right about the `&>` thing, of course.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install ucommon-utils`

`pdetach command`

There you go :)

Answer (score 1):

`kstart5` from KDE, available in the package [kde-cli-tools](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=kde-cli-tools) can help

```
kstart5 my-command &
```

We can as well manage multiple aspect of an x window if we are running a gui

---

*Sources: [Linuxhacks.org](https://linuxhacks.org/how-to-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely/)

Disclosure: I am the owner of Linuxhacks.org*

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to do this. It stops the process printing to the terminal, detaches with `nohup`, and exits with the return status if the command finishes within the `TIMEOUT`.

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=0.1

CMD=( "$@" )
#Could have some shortcuts here, e.g. replace "somefile.c" with "gedit somefile.c"

#use nohup to run the command, suppressing its output and allowing the terminal to be closed
#also send nohup's output to /dev/null, supressing nohup.out
#run nohup in the background so this script doesn't block
#print the command for debugging and to see bash variable expansion
printf "%q " "${CMD[@]}"
echo
nohup "${CMD[@]}" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
NOHUP_PID=$!

#kill this script after a short time, exiting with success status - command is still running
#this is needed as there is no timeout argument for `wait` below
MY_PID=$$
trap "exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
sleep $TIMEOUT && kill $MY_PID 2>/dev/null & #ignore "No such process" error if this exits normally

#if the command finishes before the above timeout, everything may be just fine or there could have been an error
wait $NOHUP_PID
NOHUP_STATUS=$?
#print an error if there was any. most commonly, there was a typo in the command
[ $NOHUP_STATUS != 0 ] && echo "Error: $CMD"
#return the exit status of nohup, whatever it was
exit $NOHUP_STATUS
```

Usage example:

```
>>> run false
false
Error: false
>>> echo $?
1
>>> run true
true
>>> run sleep 10
sleep 10
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to GUI, but I add this very handy answer here because it's one of the topmost results in search.

So, if you want to run something then be able to close the terminal and keep that something running, with the ability to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr:

`echo "my_command param1 param2 > out" | at now+1min`

Of course, the process will start in 1 minute.
Use `atq` to check status and `atrm task_number` to cancel the future start.

It does not work for already running processes, only for new ones.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to simply launch a command line application without keeping the terminal window around, then you might try running the application after launching the terminal with alt-F2.