# Run a program independently of console

Tags: centos, kde, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

I'm using CentOs with KDE. I want to run, for example, `kedit` via console. But when I close the console, `kedit` closes too – I think because it is its child process.

How can I run it independently?

Answer (score 3):

```
nohup kedit &
```

[nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) - stops the process responding to the HUP signal, which is what is closing it.

& - run the process 'in the background', essentially returning your command prompt to you after you run it, rather than when it ends.