# How can I run my python program directly from the shell?

Tags: linux, bash, python, shell-script

I wrote a script. When it starts, it won't stop, and it keeps getting data from the Internet. 
I can call it this way:

```
cd /User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/
python3 main.py start
```

But I would like to call it directly from the terminal like this, within the destination:

```
internetScanner start
```

How can I do so?

Comment: I wonder if the title could be changed on this..

Comment: @user606723 Feel free to suggest an edit to have it changed. The first title "How to let my programme can run on shell?" wasn't very good.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should probably rename your file `main.py` to `internetScanner`. Extensions on *nix are purely optional. It shouldn't matter here.

```
mv main.py internetScanner
```

Then, add the following line to this file, right at the beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This will make sure that when the  shell executes the file, it will know to use `python3` to interpret the content. This is known as the [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). Now, make the file executable:

```
chmod +x internetScanner
```

You can now run your program from within `/User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/`:

```
./internetScanner start
```

Your program will run in the foreground and continue running until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. If you do not want this, you can also start the program in the background, by adding an ampersand after the command:

```
./internetScanner start &
```

This will let your program run, but you can continue to use your shell. This is called job control, and there's a simple tutorial about it [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php).

If you now want to be able to run the program from anywhere on the system, you need to add the `internetScanner` directory to your `PATH`: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: Good answer. I'd recommend adding that he *might* want to end the command with an ampersand (&) if he doesn't want to wait for it and/or redirect its output and error stream to a file.

Comment: @BenHocking Thanks, I added it to the answer.

Comment: `X &` doesn't detach the process from the controlling shell, it only backgrounds the process, meaning if that shell exits it'll get the TERM signal sent to it; so if you don't want that you should use [detach](http://inglorion.net/software/detach/), `detach ./internetScanner start`.

Comment: @DanD. … or `nohup`, `disown` or `at`, et cetera. [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](http://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

Comment: It may be worth noting that it can still be named `main.py` as long as it's symlinked to `internetScanner` somewhere in $PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no other files in `/User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/` are needed, if you want to install for a single user, link (`ln -s`) `main.py` to `$HOME/bin/internetScanner`. You'll probably need to mkdir `$HOME/bin` first.

Next time you log in, `$HOME/bin` will probably be added to your PATH. If you want it available for all users, copy it to `/usr/local/bin`.

If it must execute in `/User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/`, either start by importing `os` and calling

```
os.chdir('/User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/')
```

or create a launcher script in `$HOME/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` that changes to `/User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/` and executes the script.

Answer (score 0):

Put `alias internetScanner "python /User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/main.py"` in .aliases file (for csh). For bash, put `alias internetScanner="python /User/Desktop/project/internetScanner/main.py"` in .bashrc.  After that you can use internetScanner start from anywhere.

Comment: I've never heard of a `.aliases` file. Is that something standard for Bash? or do you have to explicitly source it in your `.bashrc`?