# Running app at background in terminal at Mint linux

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint, xampp

How to start app in terminal in background? I want to start Xampp gui app starting like "sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run". App will be opened and terminal is waiting on the next row. Is it possible runnign app and use same terminal? THX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Bash script in background and exit terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/448445/run-bash-script-in-background-and-exit-terminal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)