# Start program from terminal as sudo but detached for further terminal use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

Yes another question for detached programs from terminal, but before you start flaming me, i have searched over the net but none of the answers matched my search.

[How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/264257/how-to-open-an-application-in-terminal-and-detach-it

https://serverfault.com/questions/34750/is-it-possible-to-detach-a-process-from-its-terminal-or-i-should-have-used-s

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807688/how-to-detach-a-process-from-terminal-in-unix

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157917

So i have tried `&`, `nohup`, `emac` and so on but those are not what doing what i am looking for or at least i don't know they are working as i am looking for.

I am not trying to login to the server and start some programs or scripts that will be used later or running in the background. I have tried with `screen` and it's ok for use on server.

But sometimes i have to debug or edit some things on my own pc with `sudo` access and if i start every program separately i get with 10 terminals opened which i don't need, and with 10 programs this is just too much stuff.

So if i open terminal and login to `sudo su` is there any way that i open a program like `kate` for example

`kate /var/log/mail.log`

and continue using same terminal again. and opened programs either to close if i close terminal or i can close them manually. Right now every solution that i found from the thread above or on search, doesn't work, some solutions just helps program to keep running when i close terminal, but still terminal is locked and i have to open another one to start another program or open different file.

So for final example how can i:

open terminal

login as `sudo su`

start `kate /var/log/mail.log`

and if i want in same terminal just start another program or open another file

like 'kate /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`

and get terminal still free to restart postfix

for example `service postfix restart`

and so on...

Comment: Try `kate filename 2> /dev/null &`-

Answer (score 1):

kate /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini&

or

kate /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Press **CTRL+z** to stop the execution of the program

type **bg** and press enter to let the execution of the program cont. in the background

Comment: I have tried that but, ctrl+z doesn't work for some reason, it freezes program but when i type bg it doesn't unfreeze. if i try with `&` the program stays detached but it constantly going back in terminal as i didn't detached it. so if i detach it and type another command, the previous program gets back attached, i can detach it with ctrl+c but it returns back again.