# how to change directory and spin off process

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, cd, nohup

I know how to change directory:

`cd path`

I know how to detach a process:

`command &`, 
`nohup command > /tmp/test_output.txt 2>&1 &`, 
`nohup command > /dev/null 2>&1 &`, 
`disown command &`

here's a good reference for that:
[How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

But I don't know how to do them both at the same time, this seems to be impossible. Can anyone help me? Here are some things I have tried:

```
path/command
nohup cd path && command > /tmp/test_output.txt 2>&1 &
cd path && nohup command > /tmp/test_output.txt 2>&1 &
cd path && disown command &
(cd path && disown command &)
(cd path && command) &
cd path ; command &
```

I can get it to error, I can get it to go to that path and run (but not detached from my terminal) or I can get it to run the command detached from my terminal but at my current working directory, not the cd path.

I can't get it to detach the process from my terminal and run the command from a different directory than my own at the same time.

Can you help me with this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [differences between `nohup`, `disown` and `&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/108618) (you may also find [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318428/108618) interesting).

The syntax `disown command` you used is invalid, at least in Bash; see `help disown`. In some cases `command & disown` is enough, but

> [`command`] still is connected to the terminal, so if the terminal is destroyed [...], the program will fail as soon as it tries to read from standard input or write to standard output.

So `nohup command &` seems better, however

> `nohup` does not remove the process from the shell's job control

This seems quite harmless, but if it bothers you, just `disown` the job:

```
nohup command &
disown
```

But if the job terminates before `disown` acts then you will disown *another* job (if any). The right way to do this in Bash is to [use `$!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters):

> `$!` Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background

So this is better:

```
nohup command &
disown $!
```

(Since `disown` after `nohup` is mostly cosmetic, I will omit it from now on. Use it if you need it).

To `cd` before `command` without affecting the current shell, the best way is to do it in a subshell (you tried it, but not with `nohup`):

```
(cd path && nohup command) &
```

or even

```
(cd path && exec nohup command) &
```

where `exec` makes `nohup` replace the subshell process that is no longer needed; `nohup` will then be replaced by `command` because this is how the tool works. This way you end up with one process instead of many.

Alternatively you can `nohup` an entire shell. This allows you to execute multiple commands:

```
nohup sh -c 'cd path || exit; command1; command2' &
```

(In this case `exec` makes sense only before `command2`).

Note `nohup` creates a file `nohup.out`, unless you redirect its output (see `man 1 nohup`). Where the file is created depends on the current working directory of the `nohup` process, so in general it makes a difference whether you `cd` before `nohup` (`cd path && nohup ...`) or the other way around (`nohup sh -c 'cd path ... '`).