# How do I run a permanent tunnel in localxpose?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp, tunnel

I am able to create a localxpose tunnel in ubuntu with this command:

:loclx tunnel tcp

but when I close my local connection to my server, the tunnel closes with it.

Is there a way to keep a tunnel open permanently, even when I close my remote local session? I want to be able to host a tcp server without having to keep that session open 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

See the SuperUser-Question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely).
Everything I would tell you has been said there.

The keywords for you are `nohup` and `screen`.